# How do I get back a 'refresh_token' for rails app with omniauth google oauth2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, omniauth

Months ago I created a rails app that authenticated with google using oauth2 - specifically, the omniauth-google-oauth2 gem. I had all the steps working to create the authentication and store a refresh token, but recently oauth2 stopped sending back a 'refresh_token' as part of the response. Originally I was receiving a response that contained:

```
credentials: {
  refresh_token: XXX,
  token: YYY,
  expires_at: 1374840767,
  expires: true
},
```

Now I only get back the token that expires within an hour:

```
credentials: {
  token: YYY,
  expires_at: 1374840767,
  expires: true
},
```

I really don't know what I did on the application side to change this, so I'm not sure if something changed with google, or if it was something I did. For context, my code looks like:

initializers/omniauth.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, 'KEY', 'SECRET', {:scope => "userinfo.email,userinfo.profile,analytics.readonly,adsense.readonly"}
end
```

authentications_controller.rb is where I receive the response:

```
def create
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"] 
  params = request.env["omniauth.params"]
  project = Project.find(params['project_id'])

  Authentication.create(:project_id => project.id, :provider => auth['provider'], :uid => auth['uid'], :access_token => auth['credentials']['refresh_token'])
  flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
  redirect_to owner_view_project_path(project)
end
```

**Is it possible something is missing in my initializers/omniauth.rb file?** I've tried adding the following to the options hash, but that didn't seem to bring back the refresh token:

```
:approval_prompt => "force", :access_type => "offline"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you solve this problem? I/m facing the same problem now and I'd love to see you solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The **prompt: 'consent'** is getting you a refresh token. Something like this should work:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  scopes = [
      # we need the profile scope in order to login
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
      # this and other scopes could be added, but match them up with the
      # features you requested in your API Console
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
    ]

  provider :google_oauth2, GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, { scope: scopes.join(" "), access_type: 'offline',  prompt: 'consent'}
end
```

Comment: The prompt: 'consent' did it for me

Comment: Thanks prompt: 'consent' saved me

Comment: Background: Looks like a `refresh_token` is only included when the user explicitly confirms access (which always happens on the first request). Follow-up requests for authorization are auto-confirmed because Google remembered the decision, however, auto-confirmations lack a `refresh_token` (which makes sense). This answer tells how to force consent, which ensures the `refresh_token` will be present. Note that this will query the user each time to confirm his authorization.

Comment: Very sad but you have to go to your google account settings and find Third party apps and services there. You need to delete from your google account the web page that you previously granted rights to. Only after that the refresh_token will appear. https://myaccount.google.com/connections

Answer (score 2):

As I see, it is enough to add

```
access_type: 'offline'
```

to your provider's scope.

The trick is as follows in the Google definition: the refresh token is supplied **only in the first time** that your app get access to the google account.

Deny authorization and regain authorization if you want to see, again, the refresh token beeing sent by google.

See google original definition here: "If your application needs to refresh access tokens when the user is not present at the browser, then use **access_type: offline**. This will result in your application obtaining a refresh token **the first time** your application exchanges an authorization code for a user." (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to `userinfo.email` and `userinfo.profile` in your scope.

https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/27